# Click Listener in Android button isn't working

Tags: android, user-interface, button, onclick, listener

I'm with some really strange trouble with my android click listener button! I've already done that several times, I'm getting crazy not founding an solution (neither an logical explanation) for this error.

**error**
The event handler for 2 buttons on my activity are not being executed. There is no error, it just not performance the handler action at runtime. This is the code for one of the buttons:

```
btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.listclient.btnnext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivityClassName.this, "Flag 01", 1).show();
                            btnNext.setText("CLICKED!");
        }
    });
```

And that's the button on xml layout:

```
<Button android:id="@+listclient/btnnext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            style="@style/Widget.TextViewInfo"
            android:text="Next"
            />
```

**info**

- There is also an ImageButton inside this activity, this imageButton works perfectly with an inner OnClickListener class (just like this one).
- I have already tried to make my activity class inherit OnClickListener and set it as the click listener for the button with no success.
- I have also created an class inside my Activity class, and set it as the button click listener, no success too.

I'm compiling for Android 2.1 + Google API (SDK 7)

------------EDITED-----------------

If I put in my code:

```
btnNext.performClick();
```

It's executed! I'm getting even crazy right now!
And the button is in fact clicked when I touch it, I can see the button "animation", and the click is logged in LogCat.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `listclient` when specifying or using an id. The first part is the type of the resource, which has to be `id` in your case.

Change `android:id="@+listclient/btnnext"` to `android:id="@+id/btnnext"`. Also adjust your code:

```
btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
```

Comment: My application is really big (about 50 Activities), an in many cases we use the same button name in different activities. To prevent an really big amount of widgets reference with "id/" we use the name of layout to separate the widgets.For instance, I have an "btnext" in other 2 layouts.

But i tried your suggestion, it still not working.

Comment: Two solutions: a) Either prefix them in a different way, like `android:id="@+id/listclient_btnnext"` (and use `R.id.listclient_bttnnext` in code then). Or b) Don't care and reuse them. `findViewById()` only searches in the current view hierachy (= the visible layout). So if you have 3 activities with 3 different layouts, it doesn't matter. It will find the one relevant to the active layout. (Thats why `findViewById()` always returns `null` if you call it before `setContentView()`. There is no view hierachy yet)

Comment: Hmmm... +1
I didn't know about that! I think it's better using "id/" so.
But unfortunately it's not the problem, since changing the references didn't make the clickEvent being called.

Comment: I'm sorry for the following *(because I should have done that in the first place)*: I just wondered why you didn't get a compile-error initially when using the ids "wrong". So I set up a small test project. Results: **It's apparently possible the way you did it initially, this answer is plain wrong** (I didn't know and never expected that. According to the upvotes, I'm not the only one. Never assume things, apparently.) It's not the "proper, android way", but it works. Still recommend to do it as suggested here. The listener gets executed though, so the problem is somewhere else. Weird.

Comment: Ahhh comment length. Given that, can you post some more surrounding code? Also how is your `@style/Widget.TextViewInfo` defined? *(also: just for info, I have given this answer based on the infos found under  [Accessing resources from XML - Syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml). Seems like assigning works somewhat different)*

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance over you code, I noticed when you don't call `findViewById` correctly. Change the id of your Button to "test" then try: `findViewById(R.id.test)`. Make sense?